# SET JAVA_HOME in windows bat file not working

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, java-home

why is **SET JAVA_HOME** in this bat file not overriding the environment variable JAVA_HOME?

**someFile.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET JAVA_HOME = Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_23
echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
```

Comment: Space before `=` is included in variable name, so you are not changing `JAVA_HOME` variable, but `JAVA_HOME_` (last underscore is a space) variable

Comment: @MCND this was a fully acceptable answer...

Comment: @npocmaka: sorry, i think both where answering at the same time. Is there some criteria to when to use comments or answers? edit- Forget it, i`ve seen it. Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

because of the additional space.Try this to see the value you've set:

```
echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME %
```

A robust way to set the java_home :

```
SET "JAVA_HOME=Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_23"
```

Comment: Super, just what I needed.